# R Knitr not printing model results to finle

Tags: r

I have an R script that is generating a number of plots and well as assessing a few linear models.  For some reason when I try to print out the plots and linear model statistics in a loop they don't end up in the file but when I remove the loop they get printed to file.

R/Knitr markup that doesn't work (desired lines to print with # I want this to print):

```
library('RODBC')
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')
library('reshape2')

con <- odbcConnect('yield_model')
sql <- "SELECT DISTINCT [grouping],[group],regionId,class,finalPk,avgArea,layer,runTime,random,name FROM dbo.pk p LEFT OUTER JOIN dred.dbo.yasMap y ON p.class = y.id WHERE random=1"
values <- sqlQuery(con,sql,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

values$model = "NM"

groupings <- unique(select(values,regionId,class,layer))

groupings <- groupings[order(groupings$layer,groupings$regionId,groupings$class),]

for(i in 1:nrow(groupings)) {
  data <- subset(values,regionId == groupings$regionId[i] & class == groupings$class[i] & layer == groupings$layer[i])
  layer <- unique(select(data,layer))
  region <- unique(select(data,regionId))
  defectNo <- unique(select(data,class))
  defectName <- unique(select(data,name))
  count <- length(unique(data$avgArea))
  average <- mean(data$finalPk)

  myPlot <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=avgArea,y=finalPk)) +  
    geom_point(size=4,color="red") +
    ggtitle(paste("Defect=",defectName$name,"(", defectNo$class,"), Region=",region$regionId, ", Layer=", layer$layer,sep="")) + 
    geom_abline(intercept=average,slop=0,size=1,aes(color="mean"))

  if(count > 1) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + stat_smooth(method ="lm",formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE,size=1,aes(color="linear"))
  } 

  if (count > 3) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ log(x), se = FALSE, size=1, aes(color="log"))
    myPlot <- myPlot + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,2), se = FALSE, size=1, aes(color="poly"))
  }

  if(count > 1 & count < 4) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + scale_colour_manual(name="",values=c("mean" = "orange","linear" = "green"))
  } else if(count > 3) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + scale_colour_manual(name="",values=c("mean" = "orange","linear" = "green","log" = "red","poly" = "blue"))
  } else if (count == 2 | count == 3) {

  }

  plot(myPlot)

  paste("Average Pk=",average,sep="") # I want this to print

  if(count > 1) {
    linMod <- lm(data$finalPk ~ data$avgArea)
    coef(linMod) # I want this to print
    summary(linMod) # I want this to print
  }

  if (count > 3) {
    linModLog <- lm(data$finalPk ~ log(data$avgArea))
    coef(linModLog) # I want this to print
    summary(linModLog) # I want this to print

    linModPoly <- lm(data$finalPk ~ poly(data$avgArea,2))
    coef(linModPoly) # I want this to print
    summary(linModPoly) # I want this to print
  }
}
```

R/Knitr that does print:

```
library('RODBC')
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')
library('reshape2')

con <- odbcConnect('yield_model')
sql <- "SELECT DISTINCT [grouping],[group],regionId,class,finalPk,avgArea,layer,runTime,random,name FROM dbo.pk p LEFT OUTER JOIN dred.dbo.yasMap y ON p.class = y.id WHERE random=1"
values <- sqlQuery(con,sql,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

values$model = "NM"

groupings <- unique(select(values,regionId,class,layer))

groupings <- groupings[order(groupings$layer,groupings$regionId,groupings$class),]

#for(i in 1:nrow(groupings)) {
  i <- 1
  data <- subset(values,regionId == groupings$regionId[i] & class == groupings$class[i] & layer == groupings$layer[i])
  layer <- unique(select(data,layer))
  region <- unique(select(data,regionId))
  defectNo <- unique(select(data,class))
  defectName <- unique(select(data,name))
  count <- length(unique(data$avgArea))
  average <- mean(data$finalPk)

  myPlot <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=avgArea,y=finalPk)) +  
    geom_point(size=4,color="red") +
    ggtitle(paste("Defect=",defectName$name,"(", defectNo$class,"), Region=",region$regionId, ", Layer=", layer$layer,sep="")) + 
    geom_abline(intercept=average,slop=0,size=1,aes(color="mean"))

  if(count > 1) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + stat_smooth(method ="lm",formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE,size=1,aes(color="linear"))
  } 

  if (count > 3) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ log(x), se = FALSE, size=1, aes(color="log"))
    myPlot <- myPlot + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,2), se = FALSE, size=1, aes(color="poly"))
  }

  if(count > 1 & count < 4) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + scale_colour_manual(name="",values=c("mean" = "orange","linear" = "green"))
  } else if(count > 3) {
    myPlot <- myPlot + scale_colour_manual(name="",values=c("mean" = "orange","linear" = "green","log" = "red","poly" = "blue"))
  } else if (count == 2 | count == 3) {

  }

  plot(myPlot)

  paste("Average Pk=",average,sep="") # I want this to print

  if(count > 1) {
    linMod <- lm(data$finalPk ~ data$avgArea)
    coef(linMod) # I want this to print
    summary(linMod) # I want this to print
  }

  if (count > 3) {
    linModLog <- lm(data$finalPk ~ log(data$avgArea))
    coef(linModLog) # I want this to print
    summary(linModLog) # I want this to print

    linModPoly <- lm(data$finalPk ~ poly(data$avgArea,2))
    coef(linModPoly) # I want this to print
    summary(linModPoly) # I want this to print
  }
#}
```

My header values (I also tried with no results portion at all):

```
{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
```

Hopefully somebody has some advice for me.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it's everything after the `plot(myPlot)` statement which is giving you problems in the loop, I'm thinking the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814011/using-loops-to-print-output-into-knitr) might apply to you.

Try adding a `plot.new` call after the `plot(myPlot)` statement

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The referenced source helped, I'm surprised that I didn't find it in my Google searches.  The part that helped the most was wrapping the items of interest in print() statements.