# Interleaving messages printing and plots inside a for-loop

Tags: r, plot, knitr, rnotebook

I'm trying to execute a for-loop inside a r notebook chunk to print some messages and a plot interleaved, shown in the code below:

```
for(i in 1:2) {
  print(paste0("before ", i))
  plot(i, i)
  print(paste0("after ", i))
}
```

However, the first plot appears where the second should have been and the second one after all messages have been printed.
Looking for a solution I found this ([Using loops to print output into Knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814011/using-loops-to-print-output-into-knitr))

```
for(i in 1:2) {
  print(paste0("before ", i))
  plot(i, i)
  plot.new()
  # This function (frame is an alias for plot.new) causes the completion of 
  # plotting in the current plot (if there is one) and an advance to a new
  # graphics frame.
  print(paste0("after ", i))
}
```

Which kinda fix it, but unfortunately empty plots are created for each valid plot.
Does anyone know a method that causes the completion of plotting without creating a new graphic frame?

Comment: `plot.new` _after_ your `plot` statement just blanks out what you have done.  I think that you want it before the `plot`.  Also,  do you want `plot.new` or `dev.new`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It flushes the previous plot and creates an extra blank plot. I just really need the flush part.